# Using jQuery Show/Hide

Tags: javascript, jquery

When select one as input want it to display .toggle, but it's only hiding it so far?
Also this may be a long shot but how can I write this code so that I can use it again which I will be needing to instead of having to write new classes names.

Here's my code script:

```
$(function () {
if ($(".binary").val() == "0"){
 $( ".toggle" ).hide();
} else {
 $( ".toggle" ).show();
}
});
```

My html

```
<div class="option checkbox">
  <label class="field_wrap">
    <div class="label">Show Borders</div>
      <div class="field">
      <select class="binary tug" name="show_post_borders">
         <option value="0"></option>
         <option value="1"></option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </label>
</div> 

<div class="toggle">Filer</div>
```

Comment: Is that your entire Javascript? Are you wrapping it in `onLoad` or similar?

Answer (score 2):

Your Javascript only executes once when the page is loading. Based in your provided information I think what you really want to do is this:

```
$(function () {
  $(".binary").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "0"){
      $( ".toggle" ).hide();
    } else {
      $( ".toggle" ).show();
    }
  });
});
```

The difference is that here you are setting up a function that will run every time a change-event occurs (= you changing your selection in the select box).

Comment: waht about [`$.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-showOrHide)? You will write it in one line.

Comment: Thanks this work, I tried using change() but I wrote it incorrectly.

Comment: Glad I could help. If you got your problem solved we appreciate if you mark the best answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your function in a change handler, like so:

```
$(function () {
    $('.binary').change(function() {
        if ($(".binary").val() == "0"){
            $( ".toggle" ).hide();
        } else {
            $( ".toggle" ).show();
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should be what you're wanting to do: http://jsfiddle.net/BbXYt/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".binary").change(function(){
        if($(".binary").val() == "0"){
            $( ".toggle" ).hide();
        } else {
            $( ".toggle" ).show();
        }
    });

    $( ".toggle" ).hide();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="option checkbox">
  <label class="field_wrap">
    <div class="label">Show Borders</div>
      <div class="field">
      <select class="binary tug" name="show_post_borders">
         <option value="0">0</option>
         <option value="1">1</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </label>
</div> 
<div class="toggle">Filer</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you want reusable code. Try this:

```
$(function () {
    $(".toggle_field").change(function() {
        var field = $(this);
        if (field.val() == field.data("toggle-show-val")) {
            $(field.data("toggle-selector")).show();
        } else {
            $(field.data("toggle-selector")).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="option checkbox">
  <label class="field_wrap">
    <div class="label">Show Borders</div>
      <div class="field">
      <select class="binary tug toggle_field" data-toggle-selector=".toggle" data-toggle-show-val="1" name="show_post_borders">
         <option value="0"></option>
         <option value="1"></option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </label>
</div> 

<div class="toggle">Filer</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qCeJ8/